# Space between elements in html

Tags: html, css

Consider I have 9 IMG in a html page. They will be rearranged in any number of rows or cells when the viewport of browser changes. What I want is, space between them is 5, but no margin after not at the last row or column.

The margin is not suitable because it gives the last row or column margins too.

Comment: You have to add a class to the last image to overwrite the margin. This will work cross-browser.

Comment: Could you provide your HTML code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the :last-child or :first-child directives in your CSS.
For example:

```
#images
{
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#images:last-child, #images:first-child
{
  padding: 0px;
}
```

If you use PHP or another server-side scripting language to generate the HTML output, you should better assign IDs (or classes) to the first and last elements there instead of using a pseudo-selector.

If you really want to, you could also combine both.

Comment: But it's supported in the major browsers: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Comment: @user603003 No, it isn't: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-lastchild#compatibilitysection (Though it's the most standards-conform solution)

Comment: @user603003 If w3schoolzzz are the answer to life the universe and everything, then yes it is supported. ;)

Comment: That won't work. consider having 3 rows, 3 cols. 3 img at the last row must not have bottom margin. And 3 img of last col must not have right margin. It get worse when the viewport changes. Maybe 2 cols and 5 rows which last row only have one element. This way nth element won't work either.

Comment: @Ali: Yes, I realized that after posting ;)
But is there any way to do that in CSS?

Comment: Maybe you could get the last row by comparing the x and y coordinates of the images. And then you cou set all CSS styles you want.

Comment: I've built an example that works in IE, Chrome, Opera, Firefox: http://pastebin.com/XTas0L2f

Comment: I think it must be done considering container width, and each inner image width. I really wonder why they didn't consider it in css specs. It is really necessary. I thought of some class specific margin that only apply if a defined class is present. I will see your code. Thanks

Comment: Not in a mode to add pseudo-selectors ? Then give a class name or id to your last and first element and then style it.

Answer (score 1):

You may write the code for displaying some rows of images with the margin you want, then at the image you don't want margins applied to, you link a class and provide a different style. You can also use the `:not` pseudoelement.

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-margin">
<img src="whatyouwant">
<img src="whatyouwant">
<img src="whatyouwant">
<img src="whatyouwant" class="image-no-margin">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-no-margin {
margin:0px
}
.image-margin img:not(.image-no-margin) {
0px 5px 5px 0px; //5px top and 5px left
}
```

This code means that you apply margin 0px to the images with class image-no-margin and the other style you defined (with 5px margin bottom and right) to all the other images (not image-no-margin).

The pseudoelement `:not` is supported only by Internet Explorer 9+ , latests versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera. You can add support for Internet Explorer 6+ by using a javascript library called [selectivizer](http://selectivizr.com/).

You just need to download the library and include it in the `head` of your webpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[JS library]"></script>
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="[fallback css]" /></noscript>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.images{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

I know you may have used Firebug and discovered that there is no border, but I had the same problem and adding `border: 0;` eliminated all spacing completely without having to remove carriage returns from the code.

Hope it helps someone!